# React: Bubbling up click events on nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, onclick

I'm creating a react file tree, and I have the tree setup as a React component. The tree can take a `contents` prop that is an array of either strings, or other `<Tree />` components (this enables the nested file structure UI). These tree components can be nested indefinitely.

I need to register a click event on the children of the nested tree components, but I'm having trouble getting it to work beyond the first level of nesting. A simplified example of what I'm dealing with:

```
//In App - the top level component

 const App = React.createClass({
   _handleChildClick () {
     console.log("this is where all child clicks should be handled");
   },

   render () {
     return (
       <Tree
         handleChildClick={this._handleChildClick}
         contents={[
           <Tree />
         ]}
       />
     );
   }
 });

 //And in the tree component

 <div onClick={this.props.handleChildClick}></div>
```

[If you want to see more detail - here's the github repo.](https://github.com/lukeschunk/react-file-tree)

I tried researching this question and saw people using `{...this.props}` but I'm not sure if that applies to my scenario - if it does, I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the click handling does not work beyond the first level is because your second level Tree component (the one inside the contents array) does not get the appropriate prop `handleChildClick` passed in. (BTW I think the convention is to call the prop `onChildClick` while the handler function is called `handleChildClick` - but I digress.)

Do I understand correctly that you actually want to inform each layer from the clicked component up to the top? For this to happen, you need to extend the props of the tree component that is inside the contents array - it needs to receive the click handler of its parent component. Of course, you cannot write this down statically, so it needs to be done dynamically:

Your Tree component, before actually rendering its children, should extend each of them with the component's click handler, which can be done using the function `React.cloneElement` (see [API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) and [a more detailed discussion](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement)). Directly applying this to your component makes things a bit messy, because you are passing the component's children in a prop, so you need to figure out which prop to modify. A bit of a different layout would help you quite a lot here:

```
   <Tree handleChildClick={this._handleChildClick}>
       <Tree />
   </Tree>
```

looks nicer IMHO and makes the structure much clearer. You can access the inner components via this.props.children, and cloneElement will be much simpler to use.

So, in your Tree component, you could have a render method like this:

```
render () {
  const newChildren = this.props.children.map(child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, {onChildClick: this._handleChildClick}));
  return (
    <div>{newChildren}</div>
  );
}
```

Please note that this code will not work if you have a mixture of strings and `Tree` components, therefore my third and last suggestion would be to wrap those strings into a very thin component to allow for easier handling. Alternatively, you can of course do a type comparison inside the map.